# Function to get last month value, SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-server-2008-r2

SELECT YMD, Value FROM Table

```
YMD           Value    
2014-01-01    100      
2014-02-01    200      
2014-03-01    300      
2014-04-01    250
```

I want to use a scalar or table function to get the value from previous month:

SELECT YMD, Value, Function(YMD) as prev1month FROM Table

```
YMD           Value        prev1month
2014-01-01    100          NULL
2014-02-01    200          100
2014-03-01    300          200
2014-04-01    250          300
```

Let´s add one more condition:

SELECT YMD, Value, Function(YMD) as prev1month FROM Table

```
YMD           Value        prev1month    prev1year
2013-01-01     50          NULL           
2014-01-01    100          NULL           50
2014-02-01    200          100
2014-03-01    300          200
2014-04-01    250          300
```

I have tried the following but have been getting errors with later calculations:

```
SELECT YMD, Value 
FROM TABLE as t1
INNER JOIN TABLE 2 as t2 
on t2.YMD = DATEADD(m,-1, t1.YMD)
```

Any suggestions?

I´m using SQL 2008 R2

Comment: are you using sql 2012 or sql server 2008?

Comment: `SQL` is the standard that most RDBMS implement. SQL Server is Microsoft's RDBMS product. Please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using.

Comment: I have tagged the question `sql-server` based on the use of `dateadd()`.

Comment: I´m using SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 3):

If you're using MS SQL Server 2012+ you can access previous rows in a set using with`LAG()`window function:

```
SELECT YMD, Value, LAG(value) OVER (ORDER BY YMD) as prev1month FROM Table
```

The same functionality (lag) is available in some other RDBMS too.

Edit: as you're using an older version without support for lag you'll have to use another method, like the one described by Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL standard has the `lag()` functionality that does this.  You can also write the query using a correlated subquery.  This requires getting one row from the subquery.  Here is a method that works in databases that use `top`:

```
select ymd, value,
       (select top 1 value
        from table t2
        where t2.ymd < t.ymd
        order by t2.ymd desc
       ) as prev_value
from table t1;
```

Using `lag()`, it would be:

```
select ymd, value, lag(value) over (order by ymd) as prev_value
from table t;
```

This works in SQL Server 2012+.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.*,Prev.Value
from Table t
    Outer Apply (Select top 1 Value
                 From Table  P
                 Where P.Dt < t.Dt
                 Order by P.Dt Desc) Prev
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it by using `Left Join`. This should work from **`SQL SERVER 2005+`**

```
CREATE TABLE #test
  (YMD   DATE,Value INT)

INSERT #test
VALUES( '2014-01-01',100 ),
       ('2014-02-01',200 ),
       ('2014-03-01',300 ),
       ('2014-04-01',250 );

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER (ORDER BY ymd) Rn,
                *
         FROM   #test)
SELECT a.YMD,
       a.value,
       b.value As Prev_Value
FROM   cte a
       LEFT JOIN cte b
              ON a.Rn = b.Rn + 1
```

***Result***

```
+-----------+-------+-------------+
|  YMD      | value |  Prev_Value |
+-----------+-------+-------------+
|2014-01-01 | 100   |  NULL       |
|2014-02-01 | 200   |  100        |
|2014-03-01 | 300   |  200        |
|2014-04-01 | 250   |  300        |
+-----------+-------+-------------+
```